# How to only play splash screen text when the user lands on the home page, then it doesn't play if they go back

Tags: javascript, html, css-animations, splash-screen

I have a splash screen on my website home page, and it works, but it continuously plays even after the user has went to the home page, and then they go back. Is their any way to make sure that the animation only happens when the home page loads at first, and the user sees it, but then it never happens again until the page is closed and reopened?

HTML:

```
<!--Page Intro-->
<div class="splash">
    <h1 class="splash-content">Substitute Text Here</h1>
    <h1 class="splash-content">Substitute Text Here</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Intro */
.splash {
    background: black;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: 2s;
}

.splash-content {
    color: white;
    transform: translateY(11em);
}

.splash.display-none{
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

JS:

```
const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
       splash.classList.add('display-none');
    }, 2000);
})
```

Comment: Is the point to prevent the splash appearing more than once? Why not use localStorage? `localStorage.setItem("seen-splash", "true");` once they've seen it, and `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("seen-splash"));` on page load to check if they already have?

Comment: Although it's worth noting I would recommend doing it the other way around to prevent flicker - only display the splash if localStorage returns null?

Comment: Using `sessionStorage ` could be more appropriate

Comment: Another option is to set/check a `cookie` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp